# Component Typescript vs TypeScript

Tags: angularjs, typescript, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm doing a project in Visual Studio 2017 using ASP.Net Core Web Application with Angular JS client side.  I'm familiar with Angular Js but not with Typescripts.  My conern Is that, I want to add a file which are similar with the existing files when I created the project.  When I do **Right click > Add Files > Typescript**, a file of typescript is created, but I'm wondering, What is the difference between the **file.ts** (which I just added) to **file.component.ts** (which is the pre-created files/pages)?

Comment: There is no difference. These two are valid Typescript files. The ".component" part is a naming convention of Angular for files containing an Angular component class. You should read on Angular at https://angular.io/docs.

Comment: So this means if I add a new folder with typescripts, html, and css without ".component" it will work the same way? thanks for the link btw

Comment: Yes, exactly! It's just a naming convention so everything will work fine.